# Why is the highest point of $f(x)=\sqrt[x]{x}$ in the $x$-axis $e$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate how can I prove that or how can it be calculated.

Comment: This is not really number theory; it's calculus.

Comment: When I see things like $x^{1/x}$ I usually say something like "That is an exponential, re-write it as such first"...

Comment: Companion Question: [the lowest point of $x^x$ is $\frac1e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4662246/21813).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical proof is to use derivatives and find critical points etc which is a general method and you ought to have it in your toolbox. You already have multiple answers for that.

Here is a different approach.

A simple trick works for this problem:

Use the inequality

$$e^t \ge 1 + t$$

which is valid for all real $t$.

Let $x$ be any real $\gt 0$.

Then

$$ e^{(x/e) - 1} \ge 1 + (x/e) - 1 = x/e$$

Thus

$$e^{x/e} \ge x$$

and so

$$e^{1/e} \ge x^{1/x}$$

Answer (score 2):

Write the function as $y = x^{1/x}$.  To take the derivative, use logarithmic differentiation.  That is, let
$$\ln y = \ln x^{1/x} = \frac{1}{x} \ln x.$$
The derivative of this is
$$\frac{y'}{y} = -x^{-2} \ln x + x^{-2} = \frac{1}{x^2} (1 - \ln x)$$
Since we know $y$, we can multiply both sides by $y$ to have a solution of $y'$:
$$y' = x^{1/x} \frac{1}{x^2} (1 - \ln x)$$
Now, the max will occur when this is 0.  The only solution is when $1 - \ln x = 0$, or when $x = e$.  Now, check to make sure this actually gives you the absolute max by seeing that the derivative is positive to the left of $e$ and negative to the right of $e$.  That is easy, since the only term that will ever change sign is the $1 - \ln x$.  Done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, write $$f(x) = e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(x)}$$ and differentiate and set equal to 0 to get:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(x)})=\bigg(-\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(x)}=0$$
Which implies (after dividing by the exponential term) that
$$\frac{1}{x^2}(1-\ln(x))=0$$
Whence $1=\ln(x)$ or $x=e$.

Now you just need to check whether this gives you a local minimum or maximum via the second derivative.

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{2x}\ln(x)$? That would be $f(x) = \sqrt[2x]{x}$.

Comment: Oops, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

It really only makes sense for $x\gt 0$, at least if you stick to real numbers.

On $(0,\infty)$ can rewrite the function as
$$f(x) = x^{1/x} = e^{(\ln x)/x}.$$
Note that as $x\to\infty$,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x} = 0,$$
so $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = e^0 = 1$ and as $x\to 0^+$, we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{x} = -\infty$$
so $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = \lim\limits_{t\to-\infty}e^t = 0$.

So that means that the function is bounded. We find its critical points by taking the derivative:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} e^{(\ln x)/x}\\
&= e^{(\ln x)/x}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)\\
&= e^{(\ln x)/x}\left(\frac{x\frac{1}{x} - \ln x}{x^2}\right)\\
&= e^{(\ln x)/x}\left(\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}\right).
\end{align*}$$
This is zero if and only if $1-\ln x=0$, if and only if $\ln x = 1$, if and only if $x=e$. So the only critical point is at $x=e$.

If $0\lt x \lt e$, then $f'(x)\gt 0$ (since $\ln x \lt 1$), so the function is increasing on $(0,e)$, and if $e\lt x$, then $f'(x)\lt 0$, so the function is decreasing on $(e,\infty)$. Thus, $f$ has a local maximum at $x=e$, and since it is the only local extreme of the function, which is continuous, $f(x)$ has a *global* extreme at $x=e$.